# ng not found when used with sudo

Tags: sudo

When using `ng serve` there is no problem.

When doing `sudo ng serve` I'm getting the following error:

```
sudo: ng: command not found
```

Can you help?

Comment: So what do you mean install `npm` for `sudo` ?

Comment: environment variables control visibility of executables ... which env var depends on situation ... NODE_PATH is used by nodejs and npm ... env var PATH is critical for many others

Comment: Use the full path to `ng`, which is `type -p ng`, and `sudo $(type -p ng) serve`. As explained in `man sudoers sudo`, `sudo` doesn't use the user's `$PATH` for security reasons.